# Filter some property value in post data by ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a model like the followings:

```
public class MyModel {

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Family { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int Number { get; set; }
}
```

So for example in Edit View I have 3 `Editorfor()` objects and I am interesting to filter the post data of this page, actually I want to ignore `Number` field and just want to post `Name` and `Family` Also I need the validations of `Number` be active, One way is I remove `Number` property from `MyModel` and define in view by hand and write all validation script by own, but I am interesting to know is there any simpler way in MVC. Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: How come you want to ignore something required?! And if you really want to ignore it, don't use the property when posted.

Answer (score 1):

Controlling all that validation and model binding manually is way too complicated and error-prone. You should be using ViewModels

```
public class SomeSpecificViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Family { get; set; }
}

public ActionResult SomeSpecificAction(SomeSpecificViewModel model)
{
   //...
}
```

Now MVC wil validate only Name and Family

Comment: +1 - use separate strongly typed ViewModels for each view, otherwise you risk potential security vulnerabilities and data loss issues.

Answer (score 0):

Any value not filled in the view will not be posted to the controller. However, if a field which is `[Required]` is not filled, then `ViewModel.isValid` will be false.